# RAID Volumes have Failed status

Tags: raid

When I turn on my computer I have this on my screen:

[image]

As you can see, RAID0 have Status Failed. I have this message since I installed Ubuntu 16.04. Before I had Windows system, so I think it's not physical problem. I don't know how to repair it.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> I see this screen:

[image]

1. **Delete RAID Volume**

   [image]

   2.** Reset Disk to Non-RAID**

   [image]

Comment: That screen that you are looking at is not software controlled.  Have you pressed `Ctrl+I` to check the RAID utility to see if the drive itself has actually failed?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Intel RST really isn't a 'hardware' RAID, it's built into the system firmware.

Answer (score 2):

The drive on port 1 has been corrupted or otherwise failed. I regret to say your data is lost.

Your first picture shows you had a 238GB RAID-0 volume. That requires the use of more drives than appear; only three drives in the RAID array (ports 2, 3, and 4) appear, each with 59.6GB capacity. 238-(3*59.6)=59GB missing, which I believe is the failed drive on port 1.

/dev/sda is the drive on port 0 which was not in the RAID array, from which you booted your Ubuntu.  /dev/sda1 is the first partition of the drive, the primary partition.

Comment: Is it possible to have 256GB and 56GB? Is it something like when drive on port was crashed it became non-RAID? If second answer is "yes", why port has changed?

Comment: No. 56GB X 4 does not equal 256GB.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. So, I think that drives should have 2. ^(n) capacity. Every of discs have 64GB. 64-59,6=4,4-This is what we don't see(for some reasons), but it exists. So You said that disc on port 1 exist but we don't see it. 4×64=256GB. I have additional 64GB on port 0. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you able to boot? If so, then the drive on SATA-0 was a boot drive and was not part of the RAID-0 array. You can confirm this by opening the can and seeing if there are four, or five, drives inside.

Answer (score 1):

RAID0 can't be repaired!

So the only option is to destroy the RAID configuration and recreate a RAID with the remaining disks or to do another RAID that has redundancy.

Ref.: RAID0 at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID

Comment: Is it safe to reset RAID data on disks on ports 2, 3 and 4? I don't want to have problems with this one on port 0 which works fine